# Multiscale Mathematical Morphology Filtering on Python

Tags: python, filter-design, ecg, multi-scale-analysis, morphology

For context, I'm basing my code on the information provided in the paper "QRS Detection Based on Multiscale Mathematical Morphology for Wearable ECG Devices in Body Area Networks" by Fei Zhang and Yong Lian which can be found [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5075532). I'm endeavouring to the best of a novice's ability to translate the algorithm into a Python code, but the resulting ECG graphs are at odds with the source. I will provide the equations along with my codes and follow that up with the obtained graphs.

The first stage uses 3M (3-scale) filtering to remove the noise:
$$
y(n) = \frac12 \sum_{j=1}^J K_j(f ○ G_j(n) - f * G_j(n)) + f * G_J(n)                  
$$
Where $J$ is the largest filtering scale (in this case it is equal to 3 because we will be using 3 structure elements), $j = 1, 2 . . . J,$ and where $K_j = (\frac12)^ {J + 1 - j}.$ The function $f$ is the ECG data, and $G$ consists of the set of kernels (or structure elements) defined as $G_1, G_2, G_3$ where

$G_1 = [1, 1, 1], G_2 = [0.2, 0.6, 1, 1.2, 1, 0.6, 0.2], $ and $G_3 = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2].$

The filtered signal $y(n)$ is then differentiated with $\frac1{\Delta{t}}$ being the sampling frequency and $n$ indicating the current sample:
$$
v(n) = \frac1{\Delta{t}}(y(n)-y(n-1))
$$
Then the absolute value of the differential output is combined by multiple-frame accumulation:
$$
s(n) = \sum_{i=n-\lfloor \frac q2 \rfloor}^{n+\lfloor \frac q2 \rfloor} \mid v(i) \mid
$$
Where the value of $q$ should correspond to the possible maximum duration of the normal QRS complex. This is the entire processing stage. My Python code is implemented using OpenCV's morphological transformations. And to prevent possible errors in the event of the function taking only kernels that are of type `int`, I multiplied all of the kernels' elements by 10.

**Python Code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import math

# Defining the structure elements
g1 = np.array([10, 10, 10])
g2 = np.array([2, 6, 10, 12, 10, 6, 2])
g3 = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2])
G = [g1, g2, g3]

def MM(f, G): # Multiscale Mathematical Morphology Filtering
    J = len(G)
    S = 0
    for j in range(1, J):
        K = (1/2) ** (J + 1 - j)
        opening = cv.morphologyEx(f, cv.MORPH_OPEN, G[j - 1])
        closing = cv.morphologyEx(f, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, G[j - 1])
        S += K * (opening - closing)
    Y = (1/2) * (S) + cv.morphologyEx(f, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, G[2])
    return Y
    
Y = MM(data, G) # data here refers to ECG segment ndArray

v = ([Y[n] - Y[n-1] for n in range(len(Y))]) # Here I could not multiply with Fs bc data is a segment

max_qrs = (.1)*Fs
x = max_qrs/2
q = math.floor(x)
for n in range(len(data)):
    s = 0 
    for i in range(n - q, n + q):
        s += np.abs(v)
```

**Results**
[image]

**Reference**

[image]

For further details, both these pictures employ the record 117 from the MIT/BIH database with a sampling frequency equal to $360 samples/s.$ What am I getting wrong?

Comment: What does the paper say $*$ represents? Is it convolution?

Comment: In the last bit, you don’t save the values `s`. Did you forget to copy-paste a line of code here? Anyway, that sum is a convolution, you can use a builtin function to compute that.

Comment: Yeah, assuming s is your third graph, how are you getting negative values??

Comment: `v = (Y[1:] - Y[:-1]) / dt`, and `s = cv.boxFilter(np.abs(v), ksize=q, normalize=False)`

Comment: @CrisLuengo The ∗ represents the closing operation

Comment: @Jdip s is my last graph. The one before is the differentiated one. I don't know what the 'Final Result' is in the reference

Comment: It is weird to do opening - closing, the result is always $\leq 0$. Also, it is weird to use $*$ for closing.

Comment: You don’t compute the function s, you only compute its values and discard them.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I _did_ miss that part, foolishly. It somewhat worked, though it looks like an abortion compared to the reference. Raising `s_values` to the power of 4 guarantees it to look as well defined as the "Final Result".

Comment: I found the PDF [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=568e1d936904f879671d80c563f646421c3837bb). There are many issues with this paper. Fig 2 shows how they compute y(n), but it doesn't at all correspond to the equation they show. In the figure, they put the output of the opening with G1 as input to the opening with G2, etc. This is not reflected in the equations. They also do not define what G0 is, which is used in the equations. The way their equations are defined, y(n) is always negative, but their plots don't reflect that.

Comment: Finally, it seems that OpenCV's `cv.morphologyEx` doesn't do morphology with gray-valued structuring elements, only with binary ones. I don't know what it does with your input here! Use scikit-image or DIPlib if you want proper morphological implementations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Fig 2 created problems for me to conciliate it with the equation, but they later wrote that it was "one of the possible 3M filter implementation schemes for J = 3," implying that there is apparently more than one possible definition than their designed filter.

Comment: @CrisLuengo As for OpenCV's `cv.morphologyEx`, I compared it with a cascade of `cv.dilate` and `cv.erode` functions which produced the same output. I also checked the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f) and it states that the kernel's datatype is an InputArray, which I assumed would work-- and it did produce the desired effect, unless I'm deceived... I will follow your advice with the choice of libraries though, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Cris Luengo's remark about saving the values of s, I could get around working the rest out. I stored them in an `s_values` list which I converted into a NumPy Array; and to obtain the well defined result in the "Final Result", it was enough to raise the `s_values` to the power of 4, and dividing the result by 10 will keep the results in a reasonable amplitude range.

```
s_values = []
for n in range(len(v)):
    s = 0  
    for i in range(n - q, n + q):
        if i >= 0 and i < len(v):  
            s += np.abs(v[i]) 
    s_values.append(s)
s_values_array = np.array(s_values)
s_values = s_values_array.flatten()
s_values = (s_values**4) / 10
```

**Result after revision**
[image]